# Does not work FB OAuth in the firefox

Tags: facebook, firefox, oauth, idn

There is a problem at IDN domain,  Facebook oauth when re-authorization showing a blank popup. And nothing more happens. The problem is repeated only in Firefox.

Demo:
[test page](http://%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8.%D1%80%D1%84/)

1) Click on FB button. Accept auth.

2) Refresh page. Click on FB button. Opens a blank white window.
[image: screenshot]

How to fix it? And can it be fixed?